color variable does not work with PS1 assignment in bashrc file
below is my current PS string in .bashrc
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;37m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;32m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\] $(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$


which works fine

but it is very difficult to write single color code while colors are also limited ; so create some variables and try to use that  as below
RED='\[\033[01;31m\]'
YELLOW='\[\033[01;33m\]'
GREEN='\[\033[01;32m\]'
BLUE='\[\033[01;34m\]'
GREY='\[\033[01;37m\]'
WHITE='\[\033[00m\]'


PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${GREY}\u@\h${GREEN}:${BLUE}\w${RED} $(parse_git_branch)${WHITE}$ '

but this does not work and display the characters itself

so, how can we use variables here?
additional queries

what are other color code we can use?

somewhere people use \e instead of \033; will that also works? any reference will be helpful



First, as a general rule, avoid using CAPS for your own shell variable names. By convention, global environment variables are capitalized so if you make yours capitalized as well, that can lead to naming collisions and weird bugs.
The real issue here though is that you are putting the variables in single quotes which means they are not expanded. Try this instead:
red='\[\033[01;31m\]'
yellow='\[\033[01;33m\]'
green='\[\033[01;32m\]'
blue='\[\033[01;34m\]'
grey='\[\033[01;37m\]'
white='\[\033[00m\]'



PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${grey}\u@\h${green}:${blue}\w${red} $(parse_git_branch)${white}$ "

Note how I use " in the PS1="...". That is the important part. Variables in single quotes are protected:
$ var="foo"
$ echo '$var'
$var

But in double quotes, they are expanded:
$ echo "$var"
foo


I think PS1 undergoes parameter expansion each time the prompt is printed (along with command substitution and the like). The double quote version will definitely break the git integration in the prompt.

@muru I think it does, yes, but if you set it using variables and you put them in single quotes, the variables aren't expanded and you get exactly what the OP describes. I have a very similar setup and I use PS1="..." in my ~/.bashrc and that works fine with git integration. And I tested with the exact things the OP is using (I defined a function named parse_git_branch and that is called correctly) and it seems to work.

Ah, but if you get contents of the variable in the prompt like OP does, then the variables are being expanded. It's just that bash doesn't interpret the results of expansion like it does characters found in PS1 itself. So if OP had red=$'\033[01;31m' (to force the special characters to be interpreted) and PS1='...\[$red\]...', I think they'd get what they want.

Also: did you check the git prompt by switching to directories with different repository characteristics (different branch, unstaged changes etc.)?

D'oh! Yes of course, fair point @muru, the variables are indeed expanded or I would see the variable name. Nevertheless, single quotes reproduce the OP's behavior and doubles fix it. Presumably because, as you said, the PS1 undergoes parameter expansion, but we still need the ${grey} etc to be expanded to '\[\033[01;37m\]' in when PS1 is being defined. In any case, I can see that g='\[\033[01;37m\]'; PS1='${g}$ ' fails and g='\[\033[01;37m\]'; PS1="${g}$" works.

Test my suggestion of using g=$'\033[01;37m'; PS1='\[${g}\]$ ' (I'm travelling with too spotty a network to try myself)

Yep, that fails @muru, I get \[$\033[01;37m\]$ as the prompt. But g=$'\033[01;37m'; PS1="\[${g}\]$ " gives me the same thing. Sigh. I've been playing with these things on and off for 20 years and I still can't claim to understand the interplay between ANSI escapes and PS1.

Ah well, it was worth a shot. The next best option I can think of is using PROMPT_COMMAND: https://askubuntu.com/a/1012770/158442

Yes, that's how I do it, but I have been testing with unset PROMPT_COMMAND and also mostly testing with dash to avoid any complications from my own bash setup.

Hmm, I think dash doesn't support $'...' ANSI C quoting, which would explain why you see a $ in the expansion
